# How do I add an Image Tooltip on MouseHover?

Tags: vb.net, forms, visual-studio-2013

I was wondering if there's a way to create an image tooltip on a mousehover event for a button for a form in Visual Studio Community 2013.

Ideally, the image is displayed constantly a little bit above the cursor and moves with the cursor as long as the cursor is above the button.

I am guessing that I can't use the Tooltip object for this, from what I have researched, so I was wondering what way to go about it.

Comment: why not? You could add MouseHover event to the button

Comment: See [ToolTip.Draw Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tooltip.draw(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @ElenaDBA: The tooltip in Visual Studio doesnt seem to support images, as far as I can see.

Comment: @LarsTech: Hmm, Im having trouble understanding whats going on in that example. It looks like it drawing a sketch from scratch on the tooltip. I just want to display an image. Ill keep looking into it however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try placing the ToolTip component on your form and a button control:

```vb
Protected Overrides Sub OnLoad(e As EventArgs)
  MyBase.OnLoad(e)
  ToolTip1.OwnerDraw = True
  ToolTip1.SetToolTip(Button1, "This is a tool tip message for the button.")
End Sub

Private Sub ToolTip1_Popup(sender As Object, e As PopupEventArgs) Handles ToolTip1.Popup
  e.ToolTipSize = New Size(200, 64)
End Sub

Private Sub ToolTip1_Draw(sender As Object, e As DrawToolTipEventArgs) Handles ToolTip1.Draw
  e.Graphics.Clear(SystemColors.Info)
  e.Graphics.DrawImage(SystemIcons.Application.ToBitmap(), New Point(16, 16))
  TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, e.ToolTipText, e.Font, _
                        New Rectangle(64, 8, e.Bounds.Width - 72, e.Bounds.Height - 16), _
                        SystemColors.InfoText, Color.Empty, _
                        TextFormatFlags.WordBreak Or TextFormatFlags.VerticalCenter)
End Sub
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Hmm this seems to work kind of. I couldnt use new.point so Studio made me create a new private function. Also had to change color.empty to color.white.

For some reason the tooltip pops up blank however. Also, I dont want the tooltip to draw anything from scratch, I just need it to display an image.

Comment: @RBuntu Then ignore the TextRenderer part and just do the e.Graphics.DrawImage part.  A tooltip needs to have text in order to pop-up,  but in your case, you just wouldn't draw it.

Comment: But how would I reference my .png image in DrawImage? It only seems to accept System.Drawing.Image class as an argument, which I think is only drawings?

Answer (score 0):

you could start here. It provides ToolTipImage property:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/98967/A-ToolTip-with-Title-Multiline-Contents-and-Image

Comment: Once I have the project downloaded, how would I reference it in my project?

Comment: GO to Project -> Add Reference and select the dll. Then add Imports statement in your code